# How to get the souce of JButton in a for loop

Tags: java, swing

I am currently working on a GUI project on simple POS (Point Of Sale) System. I have a for loop to add in JButton for all the menu items, however I can't seem to locate the exact index of my item in my ActionListener. Code as below

```
        for (int i = 0; i < food.Food.size(); i++) {
            int temp = i;
            name = food.Food.get(temp).name;
            foodname = new JButton(String.format("<html> %s <br/> RM %.2f", food.Food.get(temp).name, food.Food.get(i).price));
            foodname.setFont(standard);
            foodname.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    quantity = getInt();
                    if (quantity != 0) {
                        if (orderRecord.orderlist.size() == 0)
                            orderRecord.addOrder(new OrderInfo(food.Food.get(temp).name, quantity));
                        else {
                            for (int i = 0; i < orderRecord.orderlist.size(); i++) {
                                if (name.equals(orderRecord.orderlist.get(i).getName())) {
                                    orderRecord.orderlist.get(i).quantity += quantity;
                                }
                                System.out.println(orderRecord.orderlist.get(i).name);
                                System.out.println(orderRecord.orderlist.get(i).quantity);
                            }
                        }
                        orderRecord.orderRecordGUI();
                        revalidate();
                    }
                }

            });
        }
```

(A few lines are for me to check if my code is working, please ignore any `System.out.println`)

I have issue on this line

```
orderRecord.addOrder(new OrderInfo(food.Food.get(temp).name, quantity));
```

where I want to store what the user ordered into my orderRecord.

Whenever I tried to order something, orderRecord only recognize my first clicked menu item and wont change it accordingly after that. For example, I first ordered "Ice-Cream" and say "Ice-Cream" is on index `2` of `food.Food`, `temp` will stay fixed at 2 afterwards, making me unable to order other item (my order list will end up with all "Ice=Cream")

Have tried adding a `int temp` (as shown in code) to detect the index of menu item (that works with JCheckBox but not with JButton). I also have a String `name` that is containing menu item on `temp`. All of those only ended up with the same issue

I need a solution or another way to do this if there is, thank you!

Comment: Hey you might want to reformat that code. You have an if missing a { and your second last } seems to have an unrequired ). I would also suggest lining up your end braces with the start of the code where the linked start brace is. I think after fixing the code it might work because the error you listed is also where the missing open brace is.

Comment: hmm i have double checked it again and even added braces for if statement that only has 1 line of code, still not working :(

Comment: What currently happens when you run this? Could you please share the output?

Comment: hi im done editing my question, see if it makes it clearer, thanks!

Comment: This is where I'd use `Action` over `ActionListener`

Comment: @MadProgrammer could you explain more? I can't find ```Action``` anywhere on net, thanks ;)

Comment: @zhenghaoliew [How to Use Actions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html) - An `Action` is a self contained unit of work.  So you could pass in all the information each one needs in order to fulfull your requirement